# How to define a callback-Function in own Function? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm pretty new in nodeJS and came around the following problem: I defined a Function in one of my Controllers, which I want to verify a JSON-Web-Token. I  used the following function:

```
exports.validate = function (token, cb) {
   jwt.verify(token, secretToken, cb(err, decoded));
}
```

But everytime I want to run it, nodeJS gives me the error, that 'err' is not defined? In the jwt-Example there's following example:

```
// verify a token symmetric
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
   console.log(decoded.foo)
});
```

So somewhere obviously I went wrong, but I don't know what. I also have no Idea what to look for... I've done some Google searches, but nothing helped me so far.

I would love to hear from you.

Regards

//EDIT: That's how I call the function:

```
AuthController.validate(req.headers['api-token'], function(err, decoded){ 
if(err){ console.log('Error: ', err);
   res.status(401); next(); 
} else if(decoded) { 
   console.log('Success: ', decoded); 
   next(); 
} 
})
```

Comment: Why are you calling the function?

Comment: I don't understand? Which function do you mean? Like I said, I'm pretty new to nodeJS. Maybe I didn't understand the concept of callbacks correctly. How would you have done it?

Comment: There's nothing Node specific here, callbacks are a pretty common JavaScript pattern.

Comment: Sane page: http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to work with callback it should use it this way:

```
exports.validate = function (token, cb) {

    jwt.verify(token, secretToken, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err)
            return cb(err, null);

        // callback have to handle error
        return cb(null, decoded);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. There's a much simpler solution. Can you spot it?

Comment: return cb(err, decoded), right? :) So that was my mistake? I have to return the function?

Comment: @Bergi It put it in two parts, because you usually wanna do some stuff with results (here decoded) before last return.

Comment: No. I mean `jwt.verify(token, secretToken, cb);`, as I had not expected that the OP wants to do some stuff to the results.

Answer (score 2):

In the jwt-Example, the third argument to `verify` is a *function* (created using a function expression).

In your code, the third argument is the *return value* or calling `cb(err, decoded)`. The `cb` function might return a function, but `err` is a variable you are passing *to* it.

If you want to use a function called `cb` then define it and then pass the function:

```
function cb(err, decoded) {
    // do stuff with err and/or decoded
}
jwt.verify(token, secretToken, cb);
```

Comment: That's what I do. Here's how i use it: AuthController.validate(req.headers['api-token'], function(err, decoded){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error: ', err);
                res.status(401);
                next();
            } else if(decoded) {
                console.log('Success: ', decoded);
                next();
            }

        });

Comment: I updated my first post, to include it. I understood the concept so far, and thats why I don't understand, why the above doesnt work. As far as I see, I did everything right.